# 7 wonders tag confusion

Tags: discussion

Looks like we have both [7-wonders](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7-wonders) and [seven-wonders](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seven-wonders).

The actual name appears to be "7 Wonders".  is there any reason not to merge [seven-wonders](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seven-wonders) to it?

Answer (score 4):

Made a synonym and merged 'em.  Use [7-wonders](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7-wonders) going forward.